# Overriding virtual function in grandchild class

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual, overriding

```
class A 
{
public:
    virtual void foo() { cout << "A" << endl; }
};

class B : public A 
{
public:
    void foo() { cout << "B" << endl; }
};

class C : public B 
{
public:
    void foo() { cout << "C" << endl; }
};

int main() 
{
    A *a = new A;
    B *b = new B;
    C *c = new C;
    a->foo(); //A
    b->foo(); //B
    c->foo(); //C

    A *ab = new B;
    A *ac = new C;
    ab->foo(); //B
    ac->foo(); //C, why?
    return 0;
}
```

I have a somewhat simple question regarding virtual functions and overriding with inheritence. How come `ac->foo()` prints out `"C"`? The `foo()` function in `class B` is not declared as a virtual function. How come it gets overriden in Class C?

I get that `ab->foo()` prints out `"B"`, because the function in `class A` is a virtual function.

If I remove virtual from `A::foo()` and only declare it as `void foo()`, both `ab->foo()` and `ac->foo()` prints out `"A"`.

Comment: Once a function is virtual, it is always virtual.

Comment: (You can make this more obvious in C++11 by using the `override` keyword - but not using it will not alter the behaviour)

Comment: **virtual** functions can be over-ridden, non-virtual ones can't.  This is exactly the behaviour you have discovered.